# Table Replication in Oracle using Materialized Views

Tags: sql, oracle, materialized-views

I want to perform and update on the Materialized Views which i have created.
and that update needs to be performed in the remote table.

These are the steps which i am following to archive this.

There is a refresh on the view which happens every minute,
but the changes made in the view will be discarded,
changes made in the base table will be pulled into the view.

My requirement is to update the base table!. what am i missing in this ?

```
CREATE TABLE ITEM_MASTER (ID NUMBER PRIMARY KEY, ITEM_NAME VARCHAR2(200),PRICE NUMBER(12,2));

CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW LOG ON HUDHAIFA.ITEM_MASTER
TABLESPACE users
WITH PRIMARY KEY
INCLUDING NEW VALUES;

CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW ITEM_MV
REFRESH FAST WITH PRIMARY KEY FOR UPDATE
AS 
SELECT * FROM ITEM_MASTER;

CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW ITEM_MV FOR UPDATE
AS
SELECT * FROM ITEM_MASTER;

BEGIN
  DBMS_STATS.gather_table_stats(
    ownname => 'HUDHAIFA',
    tabname => 'ITEM_MV');
END;

BEGIN
   DBMS_REFRESH.make(
     name                 => 'HUDHAIFA.MINUTE_REFRESH',
     list                 => '',
     next_date            => SYSDATE,
     interval             => '/*1:Mins*/ SYSDATE + 1/(60*24)',
     implicit_destroy     => FALSE,
     lax                  => FALSE,
     job                  => 0,
     rollback_seg         => NULL,
     push_deferred_rpc    => TRUE,
     refresh_after_errors => TRUE,
     purge_option         => NULL,
     parallelism          => NULL,
     heap_size            => NULL);
END;
/


BEGIN
   DBMS_REFRESH.add(
     name => 'HUDHAIFA.MINUTE_REFRESH',
     list => 'HUDHAIFA.ITEM_MV',
     lax  => TRUE);
END;
/

EXEC DBMS_MVIEW.refresh('ITEM_MV');
```